# Django Rest Framework: serialize object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Instead of a model, I want to serialize my tags from django-taggit. I can get the object via Tag.objects.all(), how can I serialize an object instead of a model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, it had to do with the fact that I should use APIView instead of generics.ListCreateAPIView:

```
class TagList(APIView):
    """
    All tags in use on this system
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = [tag.name for tag in Tag.objects.all()]
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a really late answer and not relevant anymore, but for people that are looking for a good solution for parsing and returning tags in Django Rest Framework can take a look here:

https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer